# how to create pydantic model with dynamic keys on the nested dictionary?

Tags: python, pydantic

I have this data structure for which I need to create a pydantic model.

```
a = {
    "name": "dummy",
    "countries": {
        "us": {
            "newyork": {
                "address": "dummy address"
            },
            "boston": {
                "address": "dummy address"
            }
        },
        "canada": {
            "toronto": {
                "address": "dummy address"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to be able to run `m = MyModel(**a)` or `m = MyModel.parse_obj(a)` and then run `m.dict()` and it should return the same dictionary to me.  How can I do this?

---

What I have tried and did not work, following the instructions in here https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/models/#custom-root-types

```
a = {
    "name": "dummy",
    "countries": {
        "us": {
            "newyork": {
                "address": "dummy address"
            },
            "boston": {
                "address": "dummy address"
            }
        },
        "canada": {
            "toronto": {
                "address": "dummy address"
            }
        }
    }
}
from typing import Dict
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Address(BaseModel):
    address: str


class Cities(BaseModel):
    __root__: Dict[str, Address]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.__root__)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.__root__[item]


class Countries(BaseModel):
    __root__: Dict[str, Cities]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.__root__)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.__root__[item]


class MyModel(BaseModel):
    name: str
    countries: Dict[str, Countries]


# m = MyModel(**a)
m = MyModel.parse_obj(a)
print(m.dict())
```

---

Also, I tried this one and this one worked

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Dict


class PetName(BaseModel):
    name: str


class Pets(BaseModel):
    __root__: Dict[str, PetName]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.__root__)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.__root__[item]


class Person(BaseModel):
    name: str
    pets: Pets


a = Person(**{
    "name": "amin",
    "pets": {
        "dog": {"name": "Rex"},
        "cat": {"name": "gooli"}
    }
}
           )

print(a.dict())
```

Answer (score 1):

this one worked

```
a = {
    "name": "dummy",
    "countries": {
        "us": {
            "newyork": {"address": "dummy address"},
            "boston": {"address": "dummy address"}
        },
        "canada": {
            "toronto": {"address": "dummy address"}
        }
    }
}
from typing import Dict
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Address(BaseModel):
    address: str


class Cities(BaseModel):
    __root__: Dict[str, Address]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.__root__)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.__root__[item]


class MyModel(BaseModel):
    name: str
    countries: Dict[str, Cities]


m = MyModel(**a)
# m = MyModel.parse_obj(a)
print(m.dict())
```

Comment: You could instead use: `countries: Dict[str, Dict[str, Address]]`.

Comment: @Chris you are right